# AWS Elastic Beanstalk Git saying "Already Up-To-Date"

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I set up my php application on an elastic beanstalk environment. I configured the AWSDevTools to allow me command line git integration. I did my initial aws.push and all of the files got pushed up to my environment and it worked!

However!

Once I began making code changes, then staged and committed those changes, now when I run the aws.push command it says "Already up-to-date!" which is false, and I can't seem to find anyway to force it to recognize and push up the new changes to the server.

Anyone else run into this issue?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because the HEAD of your local repository matches what has been pushed to AWS.

I've run into this when my aws.configuration properties were incorrectly set, usually after changing around my environments but neglecting to update the local configuration. You can verify this by logging into the AWS console, expanding the environment details of the EBS environment you're deploying to, then click *Deploy a Different Version*. If the changeset ID in the top of the list doesn't match what's live in your environment, then the push is working but deployment is failing. Manually update the app version and you should be able to push new changes using git (be sure to update your local configuration).

There also appears to be a bug in the EBS client that can cause this behavior. Have a look at [this discussion thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=336101) for more info and some debugging tips.